# Fail when using TinyMCE with JustBoil

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, justboil.me

I used the [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) editor successfully and I am happy with it. Now I need the option that users can insert images into their written text. For that purpose I wanted to use [JustBoil](http://justboil.me/) so that they can upload and eventually insert their images into the text. This is my current `tinymce.init()` setup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image preview hr",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools jbimages"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic | forecolor backcolor | link image jbimages",
    toolbar2: "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent ",
    image_advtab: true,
    relative_urls: false
});
</script>
```

The *upload image* button exists now but as soon as I hit the button, the index.php gets offered for download, which obviously shouldn't be the case. When I decline the download and try to use the image upload through the *Browse* button I eventually receive following message:

> Upload in progress…
>
> This is taking longer than usual.
>
> An error may have occurred.
>
> View script's output

By the way, this is the *script's output*:

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments

Do you guys have similar experiences with this and are maybe able to help me out with this one? Any help is highly appreciated! Please tell if I shall provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit upload, 'init' block of 'editor_plugin.js' is invoked. You may open 'editor_plugin_src.js' for readability.

This js file, in turn loads 'dialog.htm' . In this dialog.htm file, set the form upload options. for form action set the path to uploader. I am using Code igniter, and they include the codeigniter code in their [github repo](https://github.com/vikdiesel/justboil.me).